# List only queue id in mailq

Tags: postfix

`mailq` lists a bunch of information relating to the queue:

```
C999C20A80    8314 Sun Dec 24 21:19:18  MAILER-DAEMON  
(host abc[x.x.x.x] said: 421 Timeout - closing connection (in reply to MAIL FROM command))  
                                         a@a
```

How do you print only the **QUEUE ID** without processing it with various grep|awk|sed?
I'm certain I saw a command for it but I didn't "register" it and now I forgot it.
Maybe something with `postsuper` or `postqueue`, but reading the man pages I cannot see any options for this.

Comment: sudo find  /var/spool/postfix/deferred/ -type f ?

Comment: yes, I know about that, I'm trying to find out what's the "correct" way to do it, without such workarounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the 'right way to do it'

but for me works

`mailq | awk '$7 ~/@/ { print $1 }'`

this will display only the id's